# Recover a previous thread although the app was sent to background

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, background

I'm trying to programme an activity that holds a count-down timer. I create this through a new thread, and when the app is sent to the background this count-down timer continues his way in his thread; the problem is when I start again the activity; which creates another thread doing the same.

So, there are some way that I can "recover" a previous thread that has been created before the app was sent to the background, without creating a new copy?

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private static final String TAG = Values.Tags.MAIN_ACTIVITY;
private TextView timeTextView;
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // GENERAL ACTIVITY TASKS (all activities should do these).
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // MAIN_ACTIVITY TASKS.
    timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activityMain_timer);

    createThread();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void buttonPressed(View view){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, 0, 0, true);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Log.d(TAG, "set time");
        getPickedTime(hourOfDay, minute);
    }

}

public static void getPickedTime(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Hora: "+hourOfDay+", minute: "+minute);
}

private void createThread() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, this.getName()+ " is about to complete...");
            mHandler.post(doAction);
        }
    };
    thread.setName("thread00");
    thread.start();
}

final Runnable doAction = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Completed.");
    }
};
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: You app is going to background or exiting ?

Comment: My app is coming from background, then it creates another thread than the existing one; and that's just the problem; I want to detect if a previous thread was created and then NOT create another.

Comment: It means createThread is being called every time...but hows possible ...if you are coming from pause ? Are you sure you are not exiting the app ? It is getting killed somewhere ..

Comment: Yes...I added a few log traces...it seems onRestart() is never called, from onPause() jumps directly to onStop(), then to onCreate() when the activity comes to the foreground again. So the process is killed and that's why the onCreate() is called again. **BUT** the thread is not destroyed! I want to retrieve this thread in the new Activity instance...

Answer (score 0):

I would be better if you can post your code. now just by guessing I am giving some suggestion
start your thread in oncreate method instead of in onresume. 
stop the thread while destroying the activity in ondestroy.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that what I want to do is not possible with threads only. I think I should use services.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in your Thread

```
Boolean isRunning = false;
```

When your thread starts put it in the apps shared preference like this..

```
isRunning = true;
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("isThreadRunning", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isRunning", isRunning);
editor.commit();
```

Now when the thread is Finished just change it back to false.

```
isRunning = false;
```

In OnCreate()  ,Read the same preferences

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("isThreadRunning", 0);
boolean running = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false); 

if(running){
   //Thread already running
}else{
   //the thread isnt running so lets start it.
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it; but I think that's not a valid solution for me; I'll explain why: I have to run code in thread, retrieve information and put information; but if the 'active' instance of the activity  has any thread running...I cannot do that.